# How can I name a person who never tells the truth about themselves?

Tags: word-request

How can I name a person who always purposely says wrong about himself (or hide the truth) if you ask anything about him, but in really he is not like that.

Small example:

> Me: Buddy, how many coding programs have you worked-out for the practical exam?
>   He: I didn't prepare anything buddy, I'm afraid, I'm going to fail in this practical exam.

*But he prepared well and scored full marks in the exam.*

One more example:

> He keep on saying he didn't look for a job change and all of a sudden comes with 2 offers in hand.

*He prepared for a job change but always hide this from other friends*

What is the suitable word for these kind of attitude person?

Comment: Curious... because it might matter... but do you actually **know** that he prepared? Some people don't prepare and assume that they're going to do poorly but through natural ability, just manage to do great...

Comment: @Catija That is one of the example, in many situation he lies like that

Comment: @Catija I was going to say the same. Often there are people who don't study but still perform well.

Comment: As for the job offers, you could call the person _wise_ or _discreet_. (It's often considered a good thing to let the fact that you're looking for another job remain unannounced.)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Somebody who never tells the truth about anything, even when they will not gain anything by doing so, is a **compulsive liar**. The following terms have the same meanings:  **Pathological Liar**, **Habitual Liar** and **Chronic Liar**.

If your friend wants to trick you into some wrong course of action  (for example persuading you to skimp on preparation for the exam), he is [devious](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/devious).

For most other reasons, you would probably need to consult a psychology textbook to find an appropriate term. Examples are:

- if your friend is worried about failing the exam, and thinks it's unlucky to say out loud that he might pass- he is avoiding [hubris](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/hubris)
- if your friend wants to pass the exam but doesn't want people to think that he's a [swot](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/swot?q=SWOT).

For the second example, again it depends on the reasons for your friend hiding this information- or on your opinion of their reasons. Some options are

- [devious](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/devious): not telling you because they think you might be better qualified for the jobs they are applying for, and they don't want you to get the job instead
- [insecure](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/insecure) or **unself-confident**: not wanting to look foolish if they do not get the job
- avoiding [hubris](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/hubris): thinking it's unlucky to say they want the job before they have an offer in hand
- [discreet](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/discreet): this suggests that it is prudent to keep quiet about a possible job move in case their current employer or other prospective new employers find out. In a small industry where everybody knows everybody else, this is crucial.
- [secretive](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/secretive): this suggests that it is strange and perhaps not nice to hide this information from their friends.

Answer (score 1):

There are a few words that may fit this description. In order from most to least likely:

> [misleader](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/mislead), n.
>
> [One who c]ause[s] (someone) to have a wrong idea or impression about someone or something.

---

> [fabulist](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/fabulist), n.
>
> A person who composes or relates fables.

---

> [liar](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/liar), n.
>
> A person who tells lies.

---

> [con artist](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/con-artist), n.
>
> A person who cheats or tricks others by persuading them to believe something that is not true.

Answer (score 1):

You can call that person a fake.

http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/fake
fake: one that is not what it purports to be: as a : a worthless imitation passed off as genuine b : impostor, charlatan c : a simulated movement in a sports contest (as a pretended kick, pass, or jump or a quick movement in one direction before going in another) designed to deceive an opponent d : a device or apparatus used by a magician to achieve the illusion of magic in a trick

Answer (score 0):

I would use the word **evasive**, or even **emotionally dependent (?)** to describe such a personality. Let me try and make myself clear...

Perhaps as a way to relate to the masses this person as you describe may resort to making up lies, as an instant reaction...

Or maybe, as people may seem pressured when they hear about the success of other people, the subject may also hide his/her successes, so the other person feels comfortable, leading to, again, relating to the other (**the bond of failure!**).

Such attitude shows just how the other person may be desperate to feel connected to others. Or that might just be me! Who knows. Have a good day!